# Syntax problem in union query

Tags: db2, union

I hope someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong in this query. I'm unable to find the cause of the error.

I have 2 tables with 2 columns each, see the CREATE statements here:

```
CREATE TABLE TableA(datum DECIMAL(8,0), colA INTEGER);
CREATE TABLE TableB(datum DECIMAL(8,0), colB INTEGER);

INSERT INTO TableA values('20160104', '1');
INSERT INTO TableA values('20160101', '2');
INSERT INTO TableA values('20160102', '3');
INSERT INTO TableA values('20160105', '2');
INSERT INTO TableA values('20160102', '6');
INSERT INTO TableA values('20160105', '4');

INSERT INTO TableB values('20160107', '5');
INSERT INTO TableB values('20160103', '8');
INSERT INTO TableB values('20160107', '2');
INSERT INTO TableB values('20160101', '1');
INSERT INTO TableB values('20160101', '4');
INSERT INTO TableB values('20160105', '3');
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to get a result with all the dates and the sum of the columns for that date.
The query that I use is the following:

```
select datum, sum(resColA), sum(resColB)
from 
    select datum, sum(colA) as resColA, 0 as resColB
    from TableA
    group by datum
union 
    select datum, 0 as resColA, sum(colB) as resColB
    from TableB
    group by datum
group by datum
order by datum
```

It keeps telling me:

> [SQL0104] Token ( is invalid. Valid tokens: FOR USE SKIP WAIT WITH FETCH ORDER UNION EXCEPT OPTIMIZE.

Both legs of the union work fine as separate SELECT statements, but when I put them together, the whole thing doesn't work any more.

Does anyone have an idea what I'm doing wrong? I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to `group by` again the result of the union. For that you need to enclose the union in parentheses and add an alias ("name" it), i.e. make it a **derived table**:

```
select datum, sum(resColA) as resColA, sum(resColB) as resColB
from 
(   select datum, sum(colA) as resColA, 0 as resColB
    from TableA
    group by datum
  union 
    select datum, 0 as resColA, sum(colB) as resColB
    from TableB
    group by datum
) as drv              -- an alias for the derived table
group by datum
order by datum ;
```

or make it a CTE (**common table expression**):

```
with
  cte as
    (   select datum, sum(colA) as resColA, 0 as resColB
        from TableA
        group by datum
      union 
        select datum, 0 as resColA, sum(colB) as resColB
        from TableB
        group by datum
    )
select datum, sum(resColA) as resColA, sum(resColB) as resColB
from cte
group by datum
order by datum ;
```

There is practically little difference between the above 2 options and I think no difference in efficiency in DB2. Pick whatever feels more readable to you. Alternatively, you could first `union` the data from the 2 tables and then `group by`. This will probably result in different execution plans, so test which is more efficient:

```
select datum, sum(resColA) as resColA, sum(resColB) as resColB
from 
(   select datum, colA as resColA, 0 as resColB
    from TableA
  union 
    select datum, 0 as resColA, colB as resColB
    from TableB
) as drv 
group by datum
order by datum ;
```

Comment: Thank you ypercube, you just beat me to the CTE solution, I was just looking into that one. I've never worked with temporary tables before. But the parenthesis will work fine too. which is different than the examples that I found on the IBM documentation, but that's another story. :-)

Comment: CTEs are not temporary tables by the way. Which examples did you find (link?)

Comment: this was what I found:  [link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21621258)

Comment: This has some similar examples: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000879.html (they have recursive CTEs there which you don't need but you can see how a UNION can be inside a CTE or a derived table)